# Django: Why does this custom model field not behave as expected?

Tags: django, django-templates

The following field is meant to format money as a two places decimal (quantized). You can see that it returns a `<decimal>.quantize(TWOPLACES)` version of the stored decimal. When I view this in the Django admin however, it doesn't do that. If I put in `50` to a field that is using `CurrencyField()` and view it in the admin, I get `50` vs `50.00`. Why is that?

```
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal


class CurrencyField(models.DecimalField):
    """
    Only changes output into a quantized format. Everything else is the same.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_digits'] =  8
        kwargs['decimal_places'] = 2
        super(CurrencyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return super(CurrencyField, self).to_python(value).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```

**Update**: I tried putting `return 'Hello World'` in place of `return super(CurrencyField, self).to_python(value).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))` and it didn't even show 'Hello World' in the shell. It put out `50` again. Does this mean that when I access an attribute of a model that is a `CurrencyField()` it doesn't call `to_python()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could try adding this to your field:

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

Also see [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass).