# Convert decimal to integer without losing monetary value

Tags: c#, integer, type-conversion, decimal, rounding

I am using a payment service that requires all it's charges be submitted as a whole number as such:

```
$205.01 submitted as 20501
$195.43 submitted as 19543
$42.06 submitted as 4206
```

I tried this first:

```
Convert.ToInt32(OrderTotal * 100);
```

But I found if `OrderTotal = $120.01` then I ended up with `12000`, with the hundreds place rounded. What I wanted to end up with is `12001`. How do I perform this conversion without rounding?

Comment: Do you mean you ended up with 12000 (3 zeros) or 1200 (2 zeros)?

Comment: do `Convert.ToInt32(OrderTotal.ToString().Replace(".", ""))` :P

Comment: What is the type of your `OrderTotal` variable?

Comment: If you started with 120.01 and multiplied by 100, and ended up with 1200 - then either your CPU is broken, or your code is simply wrong. I'm going to bet on the latter.

Comment: I just tried your code and when OrderTotal is `120.01` the resut is `12001`.

Comment: You may want to check out difference between casting and rounding http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+cast+int+vs+round which I believe what you actually talking about.

Comment: try  to  be sure that OrderTotal is correctly  retrieved and has the right type

Comment: Is `OrderTotal` _exactly_ `120.01` or could it be something like `120.005`? That figure would give `12000` using your code as it would be rounded using round to even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
decimal firstDecimal = 120.01M;
double firstDouble = 120.01;
float firstFloat = 120.01F;

Console.WriteLine ((int)(firstDecimal * 100)); // 12001
Console.WriteLine ((int)(firstDouble * 100));  // 12001
Console.WriteLine ((int)(firstFloat * 100));   // 12001

Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToInt32(firstDecimal * 100)); // 12001
Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToInt32(firstDouble * 100));  // 12001
Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToInt32(firstFloat * 100));   // 12001
```

This means one thing.... you have something else going wrong with your code.

EDIT:
Convert.ToInt32 produces the exact same result

Comment: This is not a valid conclusion.  Casting to int and using Convert.ToInt32() are not equivalent operations.  The first truncates, the second rounds using banker's rounding.

Comment: One is casting and the other is converting, but in this case, it really doesn't make a difference. @CleverNeologism

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct as per my view. If the OrderTotal is 120.01 then total = 120.01*100 = 12001.

```
double OrderTotal = 120.01;
int total = Convert.ToInt32(OrderTotal * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply it by 100 then cast it as an it

```
(int)decaimalValue * 100
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    decimal firstDecimal = 120.01M;
    private int ConvertDecimalToInt(decimal value, short decimals)
    {
        if (decimals == 0) return (int)value;
        int valueInt = (int)(value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimals));
        return valueInt;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertDecimalToInt(firstDecimal, 2)); // 12001
```